# Can't write all list to the file

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList list of some lines from text file. I am trying to find these lines in a text file, if I find it I want to write it to another text file and delete it from the original file.

I wrote a code for that, it is working but not for the whole list, sometimes take one line and sometimes take more. and give me this message:

> 1 R101 100850 0
>   Exception caught : java.io.IOException: Stream closed

```
static void moveLines(ArrayList posList, int topic) {

    //=======================To read lines=======
    File inputFile = new File("U:\\Research\\Projects\\sef\\enhancfeaturtm\\TestData\\topic\\" + "Test" + topic + ".txt");
    File outputFile = new File("U:\\Research\\Projects\\sef\\enhancfeaturtm\\TestData\\topic\\" + "Training" + topic + ".txt");

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileWriter fr1 = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fr1);

        String line;
        int count = 1;
        int z = 1;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          //  System.out.println(z++ + ": ");
            String subLine = line.substring(5, line.length() - 2);
          //  System.out.println(subLine);

            if (posList.contains(subLine)) {
                System.out.println(count++ + " " + line);
                fr1.write(line);
                fr1.write("\n");
                fr1.flush();
               fr.close();
                removeLineFromFile(inputFile.getAbsolutePath(), line);

            }
        }
        br.close();
        fr1.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e);
    }
}

static void removeLineFromFile(String file, String lineToRemove) {

    try {

        File inFile = new File(file);

        //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename. 
        File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;

        //Read from the original file and write to the new 
        //unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {

                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
            }
        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        //Delete the original file
        if (!inFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
        }

        //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile)) {
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What line is that exception occurring on? Can you pare your Wall o' Code down to something more manageable that still reproduces the problem?

Comment: It occur in the first exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
String subLine = line.substring(5, line.length() - 2);
```

You  are hard coding to take substring from index 5.

What happens when the length of line is less than 5? have a check if the line's length is less than 5 and only then proceed.

Also why are catching with 'Exception' ? try catching with a lower level exception like ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

I figure out the problem, it was because I delete the file and create it again from temp file. in that case I lose the pointer to the file.

This is the code after I fix it if someone interested.

```
 static void moveLines(ArrayList posList, int topic) {

    //=======================To read lines=======
    File inputFile = new File("U:\\Research\\Projects\\sef\\enhancfeaturtm\\Data1\\topic\\" + "Test" + topic + ".txt");
    File outputFile = new File("U:\\Research\\Projects\\sef\\enhancfeaturtm\\Data1\\topic\\" + "Training" + topic + ".txt");

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String subLine = line.substring(5, line.length() - 2);

            if (posList.contains(subLine)) {
                System.out.println(count++ + " " + line);
                bufferedReader.close();
                fileReader.close();


                bufferedWriter.write(line+"\n");
                bufferedWriter.flush();


                bufferedReader = removeLineFromFile(inputFile.getAbsolutePath(), line);

            }
        }
        bufferedWriter.close();
        fileWriter.close();

        bufferedReader.close();
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e);
    }
}

static BufferedReader removeLineFromFile(String file, String lineToRemove) {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {

        File inFile = new File(file);

        //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename. 
        File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;

        //Read from the original file and write to the new 
        //unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {

                bw.write(line+"\n");
                bw.flush();
            }
        }
        bw.close();
        br.close();

        //Delete the original file
        if (!inFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return null;
        }

        //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile)) {
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");
        }

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bufferedReader;
}
```